# Configuring Flask to correctly load Bootstrap js and css files

Tags: python, flask

How can you use the "url_for" directive in Flask to correctly set things up so a html page that uses Bootstrap and RGraph works ?

Say my html page looks like this (partial snippet) :-

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <link href="scripts/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <title>HP Labs: Single Pane Of Glass (Alpha)</title>
            <script src="scripts/RGraph/libraries/RGraph.common.core.js" ></script>
            <script src="scripts/RGraph/libraries/RGraph.line.js" ></script>
            <script src="scripts/RGraph/libraries/RGraph.common.effects.js" ></script>
            <script src="scripts/RGraph/libraries/RGraph.line.js" ></script>

 ......

 </html>
```

Here's what I've done/want to do :-

1. Created a "templates" directory alongside my Flask module and placed this html file in it.
2. Created a "static" directory alongside my Flask module but am unsure where and how many "url_for" type statements to use and where they should go. So currently the "scripts" directory is a sub-directory in the "templates" directory (I know this is incorrect).
3. I'd like to be able to reference all the Bootstrap and RGraph js and css correctly (right now seeing lots of 404s).

Can anyone direct me to correctly configure Flask (running the dev server) to do this ? Right now the js and css doesn't work.

Thanks !

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Put the `scripts` directory in your `static` subdirectory, then use:

```
<link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='scripts/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

The pattern here is:

```
{{ url_for('static', filename='path/inside/the/static/directory') }}
```

which will be replaced with the correct URL for static resources, even if you ever switched all these files to a different hosting (like a CDN).

Comment: How would this work for javascript (where there is a "<script>" tag ?

Comment: Also, do you have to define a "url_for" statement for *each* stylesheet or js file ? Is there a way to somehow say "look here for all static content e.g. *.css or *.js" (regardless of what it's called)

Comment: @bzo: you'd use the same construct in the `src=".."` attribute. The `url_for()` function returns a string, a URL to use wherever you need a URL.

Comment: @bzo: You'd have to use this for *each* URL, you cannot use this for a directory. You could write additional code that lists all files in a specific directory and lets you then use a loop to create `script` and `style` tags for each, but that would somewhat defeat the purpose of the `static` route as that would not allow you to move the static resources to a CDN.

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure if this is helpful, but I saw this around while studying up on flask:

```
from flask.ext.bootstrap import Bootstrap
# ...
bootstrap = Bootstrap(app)
```

you can `pip install flask-bootstrap` and it should help

then on your template:

```
{% extends "bootstrap/base.html" %}
```

Comment: I did this but I get "bootstrap/base.html" unresolved reference