# External CSS file do not work in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, flask

I am making a web app in flask and use bootstrap for my front end. The external CSS file is located on /static of the application. The problem is the properties in the external CSS do not apply to the elements.

form.html

```
<head>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

form.html

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class= "container">
        <h1>Application</h1>
    </div>  
</div>
```

style.css

```
.jumbotron {
    background-color: #191970;
    height: 100px;  
}
```

Comment: Do you see any errors in your browser console?

Comment: @DavidG No, no errors on the browser console!

Answer (score 0):

(I can't comment yet so...) From [Configuring Flask to correctly load Bootstrap js and css files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22047398/configuring-flask-to-correctly-load-bootstrap-js-and-css-files)

Try using:

```
<link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='scripts/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

The pattern they said here is:

```
{{ url_for('static', filename='path/inside/the/static/directory') }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try solving in this way:

```
<head>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='stylesheets/style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>
```

assuming you have a folder "stylesheets" located inside the static folder, which contains the file style.css